# How to recover an accidentally deleted queue in the Azure service bus?

Tags: azureservicebus, azure-servicebus-queues

Accidentally while resending messages stuck in the deadletter, I delete the queue. I would like to know if there is any command or step by step to recover this deleted queue and your messages or deadletter messages.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Once an entity is deleted it's gone. Unless you had a geographical disaster recovery set up in place, that queue is gone.

Update: DR on its own is not a remedy. The failover would need to happen right away (triggered manually). The issue, though, would be that the entity state/properties would be recoverable but not the messages. Data plane DR is still not available (2020-09).

Comment: how does geographical disaster recovery help in this case. If a queue is deleted, won't it be deleted as well in the replicated side?